# How to fetch values from json arraylist in java

Tags: java, json

I found many questions as mine in the stack but that could not resolve my problem.
I am a beginner in using json. I want to get the values of json object.
Below is the code which I get as response.

```
[
    {
        "empId": "9071",
        "custId": "127"
    },
    {
        "empId": "9071",
        "custId": "129"
    }
]
```

As for now I tried using below code.
mapping is my json response

```
           for(int i=0;i<mapping.size();i++)
          {
               System.out.println(mapping.get(0));
          }
```

using the print statement I get the output as shown below.

```
{
    empId: 9071,
    custId: 127
}
```

I need to get the values of empId and custId. How to do that?

Comment: Are you using any JSON library like `GSON`?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I am not using GSON .I am using JSONArray from org.json

Answer (score 0):

you can retrive values in the following way

```
for(int i=0;i<mapping.size();i++){
            System.out.println("EmpId ::"+((JSONObject)mapping.get(i)).getString("empId"));
            System.out.println("CustId ::"+((JSONObject)mapping.get(i)).getString("custId"));
```

Comment: I have tried using the above code even before .But i get this exception java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Comment: @lokeshreddy That's your problem, create a `JSONObject`, not a `LinkedHashMap`!

Comment: I am not at all using LinkedhashMap ..I am using JSONArray to get json response

Comment: these are the imports you need to use "import net.sf.json.JSONArray;",
"import net.sf.json.JSONObject;"

Comment: @ChotaJavaDeveloper If i use import net.sf.json.JSONArray .how to do that using org.net.sf.json.JSONArray?

Comment: can you share the name of the jar file which you are using. The above imports i mentioned are useful when you use "json_simple.jar"

Comment: @ChotaJavaDeveloper I am using 'java-json.jar' .And even i have the jar u mentioned .but i am not able to get the value.

Comment: Anyway  got to know my problem.Thanks to all